# What files does gradle wrapper need writeable in order to run?

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

I'm setting up Gradle with a container-based CI/CD system that has a split build vs run environment.  In build, the project's disk is writeable.  At runtime, only selected directories are writeable, and those directories are not available during build.  It's a clear separation between the two.

The problem I'm running into is that running `gradlew build` in the build step works, but then running `gradlew run` in the production environment (on a read-only file system) fails.  Specifically, at runtime it tries to recompile the project again, and fails to do so (naturally, because the file system is read-only).  But why is it recompiling if it's already been compiled?

I have tried making the `build` and `.gradle` directories both runtime-writeable.  That does work, and `gradlew` will then recompile the entire system a second time, write out to those directories, and run.  If I then make the `build` directory read-only again, it continues to work.  That to me suggests there's some part of `.gradle` that needs to be writeable at runtime, but so far I've not found a combination that works other than "everything and everything", which is clearly not desirable.  (Doing that one-time build and then fiddling with the directory mounts isn't workable as a production practice, as it's not then a repeatable build.)

I am still fairly new to Gradle so I'm not sure what the cause is.  My best theory is that `gradlew` wanting to re-download gradle initially (even though it's presumably already in `.gradle`?) is causing it to skip all pre-existing generated files, even if they're present.  That's why having one successful build fixes it for future builds, even if the `build` directory is read-only.

So my question, generally, is what parts of `.gradle` need to be runtime-writeable in order for a Gradle-built application to work in a read-only environment?  Or, more generally, how do I make a Gradle-built application work in a read-only environment, period?

Comment: You shouldn't use gradlew run to run your project in production. Just execute/deploy the artefact produced by the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use Gradle to run your project at production time. Gradle is a build tool and the `run` task that is added by the `application` plugin is only for testing purpose. If you don't want to produce a distributable and then use that at production time, but if you want to run out of the project directory, at least use `installDist` at build time and then run the project as it is assembled in `build/install/...` with the generated start scripts.